# Ode server error on stopping (as well as BPEL deploy error)

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, bpel, ode

I am very new to this and have been looking all through the apache forums and elsewhere for solutions, but have not been able to find anything.

Firstly, I have followed the following guides on getting Apache ODE 1.3.6 setup as well as BPEL with eclipse:

http://www-inf.it-sudparis.eu/~nguyen_n/teaching_assistant/bpel/installing_bpel_designer_and_apache_ode_on_eclipse

and the following guide to create and deploy a hello world project:

http://www-inf.it-sudparis.eu/~nguyen_n/teaching_assistant/bpel/deploying_hello_world_bpel_process_with_eclipse_bpel_designer_and_apache_ode

I have gone over others and these seem to be very on point and correct.

Now here are my two issues:

I can start the ODE server fine; but when I stop it I get an alert:

```
A Java Exception has Occurred
```

and in the console I get the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:     org/apache/juli/logging/LogFactory
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.<clinit>(Bootstrap.java:60)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

After a minute or two the server has to be killed as it won't stop

The tomcat-juli.jar is in the classpath (or else I would also get this error when starting the server)

By second issue is:

2) When I try to deploy the HelloWorld project on the Ode server, I get the following (in the console:

```
11:49:54,599 WARN  [ProcessStoreImpl] Deployment failed within the engine, store     undeploying process.
org.apache.ode.bpel.iapi.ContextException: Could not activate endpoint for service     {http://helloworld.localhost}HelloWorldService and port HelloWorldPort
    at org.apache.ode.axis2.BindingContextImpl.activateMyRoleEndpoint(BindingContextImpl.java:83)
at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelProcess.activate(BpelProcess.java:588)
at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelEngineImpl.registerProcess(BpelEngineImpl.java:346)
at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelServerImpl.register(BpelServerImpl.java:321)
at org.apache.ode.axis2.ODEServer.handleEvent(ODEServer.java:665)
at org.apache.ode.axis2.ODEServer.access$100(ODEServer.java:89)
at org.apache.ode.axis2.ODEServer$ProcessStoreListenerImpl.onProcessStoreEvent(ODEServer.java:641)
at org.apache.ode.store.ProcessStoreImpl.fireEvent(ProcessStoreImpl.java:592)
at org.apache.ode.store.ProcessStoreImpl.fireStateChange(ProcessStoreImpl.java:598)
at org.apache.ode.store.ProcessStoreImpl.deploy(ProcessStoreImpl.java:311)
at org.apache.ode.store.ProcessStoreImpl.deploy(ProcessStoreImpl.java:172)
at org.apache.ode.axis2.deploy.DeploymentPoller.check(DeploymentPoller.java:160)
at org.apache.ode.axis2.deploy.DeploymentPoller.access$300(DeploymentPoller.java:60)
at org.apache.ode.axis2.deploy.DeploymentPoller$PollingThread.run(DeploymentPoller.java:251)
Caused by: org.apache.ode.axis2.OdeFault: The soap:address http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld used for service {http://helloworld.localhost}HelloWorldService and port HelloWorldPort should be of the form http://hostname:port/ode/processes/myProcessEndpointName
at org.apache.ode.axis2.hooks.ODEAxisService.extractServiceName(ODEAxisService.java:226)
at org.apache.ode.axis2.hooks.ODEAxisService.createService(ODEAxisService.java:86)
at org.apache.ode.axis2.BindingContextImpl.createService(BindingContextImpl.java:120)
at org.apache.ode.axis2.BindingContextImpl.activateMyRoleEndpoint(BindingContextImpl.java:78)
... 13 more
11:49:54,640 INFO  [BpelServerImpl] Unregistered process {http://helloworld.localhost}HelloWorld-5.
11:49:54,641 ERROR [DeploymentPoller] Deployment of BPEL_HelloWorld failed, aborting for now.
org.apache.ode.bpel.iapi.ContextException: Could not activate endpoint for service     {http://helloworld.localhost}HelloWorldService and port HelloWorldPort
at     org.apache.ode.axis2.BindingContextImpl.activateMyRoleEndpoint(BindingContextImpl.java:83)
at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelProcess.activate(BpelProcess.java:588)
at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelEngineImpl.registerProcess(BpelEngineImpl.java:346)
at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelServerImpl.register(BpelServerImpl.java:321)
at org.apache.ode.axis2.ODEServer.handleEvent(ODEServer.java:665)
at org.apache.ode.axis2.ODEServer.access$100(ODEServer.java:89)
at org.apache.ode.axis2.ODEServer$ProcessStoreListenerImpl.onProcessStoreEvent(ODEServer.java:641)
at org.apache.ode.store.ProcessStoreImpl.fireEvent(ProcessStoreImpl.java:592)
at org.apache.ode.store.ProcessStoreImpl.fireStateChange(ProcessStoreImpl.java:598)
at org.apache.ode.store.ProcessStoreImpl.deploy(ProcessStoreImpl.java:311)
at org.apache.ode.store.ProcessStoreImpl.deploy(ProcessStoreImpl.java:172)
at org.apache.ode.axis2.deploy.DeploymentPoller.check(DeploymentPoller.java:160)
at org.apache.ode.axis2.deploy.DeploymentPoller.access$300(DeploymentPoller.java:60)
at org.apache.ode.axis2.deploy.DeploymentPoller$PollingThread.run(DeploymentPoller.java:251)
Caused by: org.apache.ode.axis2.OdeFault: The soap:address     http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld used for service     {http://helloworld.localhost}HelloWorldService and port HelloWorldPort should be of the form http://hostname:port/ode/processes/myProcessEndpointName
at org.apache.ode.axis2.hooks.ODEAxisService.extractServiceName(ODEAxisService.java:226)
at org.apache.ode.axis2.hooks.ODEAxisService.createService(ODEAxisService.java:86)
at org.apache.ode.axis2.BindingContextImpl.createService(BindingContextImpl.java:120)
at org.apache.ode.axis2.BindingContextImpl.activateMyRoleEndpoint(BindingContextImpl.java:78)
... 13 more
```

As far as I can tell the BPEL was configured to run on ODE environment, but I cannot seem to get much more out of this trace.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Could you please post the `<service>` element with the soap address?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the ODE service address:

```
http://localhost:8080/ode/processes/HelloWorld
```

As I can see from your logs your address is

```
http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld
```

It worked for me.